# Create semi transparent Uiview in Swift 3

Tags: uiview, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I'm using swift 3 Xcode 8.1,  I want to make a semi transparent UiView over details UiView that prevent user from provide rating and comment unless he is logged, such as appears in image below, How can I make this Semi transparent View
[semi transparent UiView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mivfT.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

> customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)